# Showing certain li's after hiding other ul's and li's using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

On this [site](https://planelogix.com/index.php/stay-current) I am having trouble with the JQuery I made to hide/show options. If you click the radio buttons you can hide different options, but doing so also hides some of the bullet points within the options. I think it's because my code is saying to hide all the li's within the div "row-fluid" but I don't know how to have it stop short of affecting li's below the first level that I want to hide.

The code I'm using is:

```
<div align="left" id="rdoBoxes">

    <h2>Help me choose</h2>
    <input class="rdo0" type="radio" name="selector1" value ="all" checked>Show me everything<br>
    <input class="rdo1" type="radio" name="selector1" value="full">I want a hands-off ownership experience that will keep my {modal /images/productImages/professional_binder.jpg|title=Highly organized, mylar reinforced, tabbed binder. A sophisticated touch for the sophisticated pilot.}Executive Binder{/modal} up to date via insert shipments, professionally transcribe (including parts and inspections) unlimited records per year, and provide 48 hour turn around support<br>
    <input class="rdo2" type="radio" name="selector1" value="mid">I want to stay completely digital and have to 10 records professionally transcribed (including parts and inspections) per year<br>
    <input class="rdo3" type="radio" name="selector1" value="diy" >I'm interested in doing everything on my own using the {modal /images/Web-Portal-Screenshot-890PM-cropped-optimized.jpg|title=PlaneLogiX Web Portal}easy to use interface{/modal}

</div>

{source 0}

<script type="text/javascript">
//show all

$(".rdo0").click(function(){

    $("div.row-fluid ul:nth-child(1) li:nth-child(1)").removeClass('hidden');
    $("div.row-fluid ul:nth-child(1) li:nth-child(2)").removeClass('hidden');
    $("div.row-fluid ul:nth-child(1) li:nth-child(3)").removeClass('hidden');
    $("div.row-fluid ul:nth-child(2) li:nth-child(1)").removeClass('hidden');
    $("div.row-fluid ul:nth-child(2) li:nth-child(2)").removeClass('hidden');
    $("div.row-fluid ul:nth-child(2) li:nth-child(3)").removeClass('hidden');
        $("div.row-fluid ul:nth-child(3) li:nth-child(1)").removeClass('hidden');
    $("div.row-fluid").children("ul").removeClass('hidden');
})

//Show Premium
$(".rdo1").click(function(){
    $("div.row-fluid ul:nth-child(1) li:nth-child(3)").removeClass('hidden');
    $("div.row-fluid ul:nth-child(2) li:nth-child(3)").removeClass('hidden');
        $("div.row-fluid").children("ul").removeClass('hidden');
    $("div.row-fluid ul:nth-child(1) li:nth-child(1)").addClass('hidden');
//  $("div.rsm_fixed_height ul:nth-child(1) li:nth-child(3)").removeclass('hidden');
    $("div.row-fluid ul:nth-child(1) li:nth-child(2)").addClass('hidden');
    $("div.row-fluid ul:nth-child(2) li:nth-child(1)").addClass('hidden');
    $("div.row-fluid ul:nth-child(2) li:nth-child(2)").addClass('hidden');


})

//Show Mid Tier
$(".rdo2").click(function(){

    $("div.row-fluid ul:nth-child(1) li:nth-child(2)").removeClass('hidden');
    $("div.row-fluid ul:nth-child(2) li:nth-child(2)").removeClass('hidden');
    $("div.row-fluid").children("ul").removeClass('hidden');
    $("div.row-fluid ul:nth-child(1) li:nth-child(1)").addClass('hidden');
    $("div.row-fluid ul:nth-child(1) li:nth-child(3)").addClass('hidden');
    $("div.row-fluid ul:nth-child(2) li:nth-child(1)").addClass('hidden');
    $("div.row-fluid ul:nth-child(2) li:nth-child(3)").addClass('hidden');



})

//Show DIY
$(".rdo3").click(function(){
    $("div.row-fluid ul:nth-child(1) li:nth-child(1)").removeClass('hidden');
    $("div.row-fluid ul:nth-child(2) li:nth-child(1)").removeClass('hidden');
    $("div.row-fluid").children("ul").removeClass('hidden');
    $("div.row-fluid ul:nth-child(1) li:nth-child(2)").addClass('hidden');
    $("div.row-fluid ul:nth-child(1) li:nth-child(3)").addClass('hidden');
    $("div.row-fluid ul:nth-child(2) li:nth-child(2)").addClass('hidden');
    $("div.row-fluid ul:nth-child(2) li:nth-child(3)").addClass('hidden');
})


</script>

{/source}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xhgdys43/1/), based on your markup, so must work for you. Just use n-th child pseudoclass to hide or show child li element with desired index

```
$('.thumbnails .rsm_container:nth-child(2)').hide();
```

Comment: that totally worked, thank you! I guess my only problem now is that I don't know why the options change sizes when you pick different radio buttons. Like that was my original issue and then trying to figure that out I noticed this much bigger issue which you've now fixed.

Comment: I'm trying to adapt your methods to other areas of [my site](https://planelogix.com/index.php/packages-pricing/packages) but I can't get it to work. It seems your method takes the columns? In this section it's not column based as you can see from the current buttons. Thank you again!!

Comment: I looked your link, there you have 4 ul elments and 2 li element inside each of them, so use selector like $('.thumbnails:nth-child(x) .rsm_container:nth-child(y)'); where x - is your packages row (from 1 to 4), and y - is your packages columnt inside row (from 1 to 2)

Comment: Fantastic advice! Thank you so much! I got it working thanks to your help :D

Comment: By the way, I'm really sorry to keep asking you stuff, but do you know why the boxes [don't hold their shape here](https://planelogix.com/index.php/stay-current) but do in the [second page](https://planelogix.com/index.php/packages-pricing/packages) you helped me with?

Comment: I've looked your link, so when you click checkboxes the width of <div class="rt-block rt-mainbody-block"> - your main container for your web portal plans changes. Your blocks for each plan have percentage width to make them be aligned by three per row, and percent width depends on width of parent block. So when parent container width changes,  width of this block changes too. Temporary solution is to add to your <div class="rt-block rt-mainbody-block"> css width: 100%

Answer (score 0):

Wrapping your desired content in span tags, and making the appropriate changes in jQuery, seems to have helped:

```js
$(".rdo0").click(function(){

    $("div.row-fluid ul:nth-child(1) li:nth-child(1) span").removeClass('hidden');
    $("div.row-fluid ul:nth-child(1) li:nth-child(2) span").removeClass('hidden');
    $("div.row-fluid ul:nth-child(1) li:nth-child(3) span").removeClass('hidden');
    $("div.row-fluid ul:nth-child(2) li:nth-child(1) span").removeClass('hidden');
    $("div.row-fluid ul:nth-child(2) li:nth-child(2) span").removeClass('hidden');
    $("div.row-fluid ul:nth-child(2) li:nth-child(3) span").removeClass('hidden');
        $("div.row-fluid ul:nth-child(3) li:nth-child(1) span").removeClass('hidden');
    $("div.row-fluid").children("span").removeClass('hidden');
})

//Show Premium
$(".rdo1").click(function(){
    $("div.row-fluid ul:nth-child(1) li:nth-child(3) span").removeClass('hidden');
    $("div.row-fluid ul:nth-child(2) li:nth-child(3) span").removeClass('hidden');
        $("div.row-fluid").children("span").removeClass('hidden');
    $("div.row-fluid ul:nth-child(1) li:nth-child(1) span").addClass('hidden');
//  $("div.rsm_fixed_height ul:nth-child(1) li:nth-child(3)").removeclass('hidden');
    $("div.row-fluid ul:nth-child(1) li:nth-child(2) span").addClass('hidden');
    $("div.row-fluid ul:nth-child(2) li:nth-child(1) span").addClass('hidden');
    $("div.row-fluid ul:nth-child(2) li:nth-child(2) span").addClass('hidden');


})

//Show Mid Tier
$(".rdo2").click(function(){

    $("div.row-fluid ul:nth-child(1) li:nth-child(2) span").removeClass('hidden');
    $("div.row-fluid ul:nth-child(2) li:nth-child(2) span").removeClass('hidden');
    $("div.row-fluid").children("span").removeClass('hidden');
    $("div.row-fluid ul:nth-child(1) li:nth-child(1) span").addClass('hidden');
    $("div.row-fluid ul:nth-child(1) li:nth-child(3) span").addClass('hidden');
    $("div.row-fluid ul:nth-child(2) li:nth-child(1) span").addClass('hidden');
    $("div.row-fluid ul:nth-child(2) li:nth-child(3) span").addClass('hidden');



})

//Show DIY
$(".rdo3").click(function(){
    $("div.row-fluid ul:nth-child(1) li:nth-child(1) span").removeClass('hidden');
    $("div.row-fluid ul:nth-child(2) li:nth-child(1) span").removeClass('hidden');
    $("div.row-fluid").children("span").removeClass('hidden');
    $("div.row-fluid ul:nth-child(1) li:nth-child(2) span").addClass('hidden');
    $("div.row-fluid ul:nth-child(1) li:nth-child(3) span").addClass('hidden');
    $("div.row-fluid ul:nth-child(2) li:nth-child(2) span").addClass('hidden');
    $("div.row-fluid ul:nth-child(2) li:nth-child(3) span").addClass('hidden');
})
```

```css
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div align="left" id="rdoBoxes">

    <h2>Help me choose</h2>
    <input class="rdo0" type="radio" name="selector1" value ="all" checked>Show me everything<br>
    <input class="rdo1" type="radio" name="selector1" value="full">I want a hands-off ownership experience that will keep my {modal /images/productImages/professional_binder.jpg|title=Highly organized, mylar reinforced, tabbed binder. A sophisticated touch for the sophisticated pilot.}Executive Binder{/modal} up to date via insert shipments, professionally transcribe (including parts and inspections) unlimited records per year, and provide 48 hour turn around support<br>
    <input class="rdo2" type="radio" name="selector1" value="mid">I want to stay completely digital and have to 10 records professionally transcribed (including parts and inspections) per year<br>
    <input class="rdo3" type="radio" name="selector1" value="diy" >I'm interested in doing everything on my own using the {modal /images/Web-Portal-Screenshot-890PM-cropped-optimized.jpg|title=PlaneLogiX Web Portal}easy to use interface{/modal}

</div>
        
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <span>
                         First Line
                    </span>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <span>
                         Second Line
                    </span>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <span>
                         Third Line
                    </span>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <span>
                         First Line
                    </span>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <span>
                         Second Line
                    </span>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <span>
                         Third Line
                    </span>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use a cleaner code. Like this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/qsyogckx/2/

**Warning:**

Do not use `.row-fluid` in the selector because it is very common to have a lot of `.row-fluid` in your document.

The use of `click` event for radios may be a bad practice. If you click in a already checked radio the event will be called. Keep it in mind.

Encapsulate your radio buttons inside a `<label>`, so the users don't have to click exactly in the circle to check the option.

```
<h2>Help me choose</h2>
<label><input class="rdo0" type="radio" name="selector1" value ="all" checked>Show me everything</label>
 <br>
 <label><input class="rdo1" type="radio" name="selector1" value="full">I want a hands-off ownership experience that will keep my</label>
 <br>
 <label><input class="rdo2" type="radio" name="selector1" value="mid">I want to stay completely digital and have to 10 records professionally transcribed (including parts and inspections) per year</label>
 <br>
 <label><input class="rdo3" type="radio" name="selector1" value="diy" >I'm interested in doing everything on my own using the</label>

<div id="myThings">
    <ul class="premium">
        <li>1 premium</li>
        <li>2 premium</li>
        <li>3 premium</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="midTier">
        <li>1 midTier</li>
        <li>2 midTier</li>
        <li>3 midTier</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="diy">
        <li>1 diy</li>
        <li>2 diy</li>
        <li>3 diy</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Jquery:

```
$('input[name="selector1"]').change(function () {

    var selected = $('input[name="selector1"]:checked').val();
    var $div = $('#myThings');

    if (selected == 'all') {
        $div.find('ul').show();
    } else if (selected == 'full'){
        $div.find('ul:not(.premium)').hide();
        $div.find('ul.premium').show();
    } else if (selected == 'mid'){
        $div.find('ul:not(.midTier)').hide();
        $div.find('ul.midTier').show();
    } else {
        //....
    }

});
```

Comment: I appreciate this input and I like your answer, the only issue is that making the div's is difficult because they are made through RSMemberships and I didn't make them. I tried using your fix but I think to do it fully requires skills I don't have. thanks again!

Comment: In that case @dajnz answer should solve your problem. But don't say that you don't have those skills because you do have!